# Working byte values and convert it to numeric

Tags: python

I have some values like this one:

```
b'11.9905 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n929.335 ; 1091.91 ; 0\r\n0 ; 851.954 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0\r\n11.9838 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n945.956 ; 1091.82 ; 0\r\n0 ; 836.356 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0\r\n11.9847 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n954.656 ; 1101.53 ; 0\r\n0 ; 839.958 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0\r\n'
```

And I need convert it to numeric values.

What I'm doing right now is:

```
  # t is the byte showed before

  trama = str(t).replace('\\r\\n',';')
  trama = trama.replace(' ','')
  trama = trama.strip("b\'")
  values = trama.split(';')
  # Appears an empty value at the end. I delete it
  if len(values[-1]) == 0:
    values.pop(-1)

  final = []
  for i in values:
    try:
      v = int(i)
    except:
      v = float(i)
    final.append(v)

  print(final)
```

Actually it's working, but I'm pretty sure there is an easy way to do the same, converting directly the byte, `t`. Does somebody know how to do it?

*PS: Am I working correctly with the `NAN` values?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have bytes, I'd try something like this:

```
sample_data = b'11.9905 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n929.335 ; 1091.91 ; 0\r\n0 ; 851.954 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0\r\n11.9838 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n945.956 ; 1091.82 ; 0\r\n0 ; 836.356 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0\r\n11.9847 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n954.656 ; 1101.53 ; 0\r\n0 ; 839.958 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0\r\n'

numbers = [
    float(i.strip().decode()) for i in sample_data.split()
    if i.strip().decode() not in [";", "NAN"]
]

print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[11.9905, 929.335, 1091.91, 0.0, 0.0, 851.954, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.9838, 945.956, 1091.82, 0.0, 0.0, 836.356, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.9847, 954.656, 1101.53, 0.0, 0.0, 839.958, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```